# Simple Cell with AsyncDisplayKit Layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, asyncdisplaykit

I'm trying to build the following design with Facebook's AsyncDisplayKit and I have problems building the Cells and the TableHeaderView.

**Design:**

[image]

**Cells:**

So each Cell has a `ASImageNode` and a `ASEditableTextNode` with the following Layout:

```
override func layoutSpecThatFits(_ constrainedSize: ASSizeRange) -> ASLayoutSpec {
    var cellChildren = [ASLayoutElement]()

    let iconTextfieldStack = ASStackLayoutSpec.horizontal()
    iconTextfieldStack.alignItems = .center
    iconTextfieldStack.justifyContent = .start
    iconTextfieldStack.style.flexShrink = 1.0
    iconTextfieldStack.style.flexGrow = 1.0

    _iconImageView.style.preferredSize = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    cellChildren.append(ASInsetLayoutSpec(insets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10), child: _iconImageView))

    _textField.style.spacingBefore = 10
    cellChildren.append(ASInsetLayoutSpec(insets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 10), child: _textField))

    iconTextfieldStack.children = cellChildren


    return ASInsetLayoutSpec(insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0), child: iconTextfieldStack)
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the 3rd rows `ASEditableTextNode` exceeds the Cells width (first problem). The other thing is that the `ASEditableTextNode` doesn't expands its height (and the cells height) to display the lines of the `ASEditableTextNode` text. Also I'm getting this warning:

```
-[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on <UIRemoteKeyboardWindow: 0x1024c9c00; frame = (0 0; 375 667); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x17022e4c0>> without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring.
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx to the slack group I have solved the issue by changing the function to:

```
override func layoutSpecThatFits(_ constrainedSize: ASSizeRange) -> ASLayoutSpec {
    var cellChildren = [ASLayoutElement]()

    let iconTextfieldStack = ASStackLayoutSpec.horizontal()
    iconTextfieldStack.alignItems = .center
    iconTextfieldStack.justifyContent = .start
    iconTextfieldStack.style.flexShrink = 1.0
    iconTextfieldStack.style.flexGrow = 1.0

    _iconImageView.style.preferredSize = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    _iconImageView.style.alignSelf = .start
    cellChildren.append(ASInsetLayoutSpec(insets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10), child: _iconImageView))

    _textField.style.spacingBefore = 10

    let textInset = ASInsetLayoutSpec(insets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 10, 10), child: _textField)
    textInset.style.flexShrink = 1.0

    cellChildren.append(textInset)

    iconTextfieldStack.children = cellChildren


    return iconTextfieldStack
}
```

The main key was to add `flexShrink` to `ASInsetLayoutSpec` of the textfield